# Aiohttp and NGINX running in Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, nginx, aiohttp

### Long story short

I would like to run aiohttp backend services on a nginx webserver. Both should be running in docker containers. Furthermore my frontend angular application should access my backend services.

### Expected behaviour

I expect that the nginx webserver could connect to my backend system aiohttp, running in docker.

### Actual behaviour

I am always getting an error in the docker logs while I am trying to call a GET request on my aiohttp backend service.

> nginx_1        | 2018/09/29 13:48:03 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /toolservice/volatility?command=pslist HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:80/toolservice/volatility?command=pslist", host: "localhost"
>   nginx_1        | 172.19.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2018:13:48:03 +0000] "GET /toolservice/volatility?command=pslist HTTP/1.1" 502 576 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" "-"

### Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

    nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - toolservice
        - ifs
      ports:
       - "80:80"

    ifs:
      restart: always
      build: ../ifsbackend
      ports:
        - "8002:8000"

    toolservice:
      restart: always
      build: ../ToolService
      ports:
        - "8001:8000"
```

### Dockerfile nginx webserver

```
FROM nginx:1.13-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY conf/server.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

### Dockerfile aiohttp backend

```
FROM python:3.6.6-alpine
COPY tool /
COPY requirements.txt /
COPY toolservice_config.yaml /
RUN apk update && apk add \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    gcc \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install virtualenv
RUN python3 -m virtualenv --python=python3 virtualenv
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "python", "server.py" ]
```

### Nginx webserver config

```
#upstream toolservice {
 # server 0.0.0.0:8001 fail_timeout=0;
#}

server {
    listen 80;

    #server_name localhost;
    proxy_buffers 8 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k;

    location /toolservice {
        proxy_pass http://toolservice;
        proxy_redirect default;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    }
    location /ifs {
      proxy_pass http://ifs;
      proxy_redirect default;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

### Aiohttp toolservice backend

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import setup_routes
from settings import config

app = web.Application()
setup_routes(app)
app['config'] = config
web.run_app(app, port=8001)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aiohttp is running on the port 8001 in the container `toolservice`, but your proxying to the port 80.

```
proxy_pass http://toolservice;
```

Try proxying to 8001:

```
proxy_pass http://toolservice:8001;
```

Maybe you will need to fix publishing of the port for `toolservice` container - I'm not 100% sure:

```
  ports:
    - "8001:8001"
```